# How to sum three columns in qlickview (two from table1 and one from table2)

Tags: sum, qlikview

I need to create a 4th column in either table as a sum of columns 1,2 and 3. How can I do it?.

```
LOAD column1, 
     KeyColumn 
FROM
[C:\Qlik\file1.xlsx]
 (ooxml, embedded labels, table is sheet1);

LOAD column2, 
     column3, 
     KeyColumn 
FROM
[C:\Qlik\file1.xlsx]
(ooxml, embedded labels, table is sheet2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your LOAD script into a INLINE version, so it is not depending on
external files and other users can copy and paste it easy.

My LOAD script:

```
Data:
LOAD * INLINE [
column1, KeyColumn
1, Product_A
2, Product_B
3, Product_C
];

OUTER JOIN
LOAD * INLINE [
column2, column3, KeyColumn
10, 100, Product_A
20, 200, Product_B
30, 300, Product_C
];
```

I use the outer join to be sure that all values for KeyColumn are in the resulting table.

In the dashboard I load all available columns and get:

[image: three columns]

Next step is to iterate over the existing values and add the three columns and store them in column4.

```
LOAD  
Num#(column1 ,'##.###') + Num#(column2 ,'##.###') + Num#(column3 ,'##.###') as column4
Resident Data;
```

Attention. This

```
column1 + column2 + column3  as column4
```

will **not** work!

After adding the new column to the dashboard you get:

[image: four columns]

I hope thats what you were asking for.

**Update** after comments.

In your case

```
Data:
LOAD column1, 
     KeyColumn 
FROM
[C:\Qlik\file1.xlsx]
 (ooxml, embedded labels, table is sheet1);

OUTER JOIN 
LOAD column2, 
     column3, 
     KeyColumn 
FROM
[C:\Qlik\file1.xlsx]
(ooxml, embedded labels, table is sheet2);

LOAD  
Num#(column1 ,'##.###') + Num#(column2 ,'##.###') + Num#(column3 ,'##.###') as column4
Resident Data;
```

should work.

Comment: Ok, but if I need to use an external file? I've simplified the example; but both tables (sheets) have lots of rows.

Comment: The way you load the data does not matter. Just add the third LOAD statement and you should be fine.

Comment: I've tried but didn´t work. Perhaps I wasn´t clear. From your example, a need a bar char with the number 666. This number is the sum of all the columns.

Comment: If your requirement changed, what about asking a new question?